# Prevent calling async method while the same instance is under process

Tags: c#, async-await

In my Web Application, I have created a method that creates a GET request according to the passed URL and then create a GET call using HttpClient. The problem is some GET calls may take long time to complete and while that request is under process, user can ask for the same URL again and there is of course another GET call to the same URL, for example user can call "www.google.com" many times while the former call is under process and has not completed yet.

I want to prevent this behavior, I want if there is same GET call under process, prevent any further GET calls to the same URL. Here is my code, But I don't know how to achieve this:

```
    var request = new RequestInfo(URL) { HttpMethod = "GET" };

    //here if the same URL is under process I want to prevent calling request.Send()
    if (await request.Send())
         {
           // other codes
         }
```

Comment: then go for *Mutual Exclusion* and place the code block under lock probably

Comment: so I should first to find if there is any same request and then go for Mutual Exclusion. am I right? but how ? @Rahul

Comment: You could use a waithandle : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx.  Wait handles are better (than locks) if you send and receive code are in different methods.

Comment: @jdweng my problem is how to find if there is any same request and then yes, probably Wait handles may work. Do you any idea or code sample that may help!  Thanks

Comment: Look into SignalR.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII signalR?

Comment: I can't use SignalR, any way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pretty obvious, that some sort of registry for pending calls is required. 
You should consider some things before the actual implementation nevertheless.

**Should this method be thread-safe?** 
It should, if it will be invoked from multiple threads concurrently.

If multithreading issues are not the case, then simple `Dictionary<string, Task>` (you may want to use `Task<T>` here instead) will be enough. Here is a small snippet to get the idea.

```
private readonly IDictionary<string, Task> _requestRegistry = new Dictionary<string, Task>();

Task MakeRequestAsync(string url)
{
    if (_requestRegistry.TryGetValue(url, out var existingTask))
    {
        return existingTask;
    }

    var request = new RequestInfo(url) { HttpMethod = "GET" };
    var responseTask = request.Send();

    _requestRegistry.Add(url, responseTask);

    return responseTask;
}
```

Implementation will be a bit more complex for the concurrent case, as far as it's necessary to avoid race conditions for the shared registry field. We, probably, want to use existing instruments instead of manual locking, therefore we will utilize`ConcurrentDictionary` type here. Code may look similar to this now.

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task> _requestRegistry = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task>();

Task MakeRequestAsync(string url)
{
    return _requestRegistry.GetOrAdd(url, _ =>
    {
        var request = new RequestInfo(url) { HttpMethod = "GET" };
        return request.Send();
    });
}
```

But actually there is a small issue with such approach — your delegate may be called twice, because current concurrent dictionary implementation invokes `valueFactory` before any locking is made as you can see from the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,1069). You should decide whether it's a problem for your scenario.

Fortunately, there is a neat and simple hack for this problem as well — our `valueFactory` should become lazy. It's still possible in this case that `valueFactory` will be invoked twice, but with the only web request.

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Task>> _requestRegistry = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Task>>();

Task MakeRequestAsync(string url)
{
    var lazyRequest = _requestRegistry.GetOrAdd(url, _ => new Lazy<Task>(() =>
    {
        var request = new RequestInfo(url) {HttpMethod = "GET"};
        return request.Send();
    }));

    return lazyRequest.Value;
}
```

**Do you expect results to become stale?**

If the answer is yes, than it's not safe to return existing responses from the registry due to their age, only pending tasks may be considered healthy. It means you should remove tasks on completion. Snippet again to get the idea

```
request.Send()
    .ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        _requestRegistry.Remove(url);
    });
```

**Do you expect to have limited set of urls?**

It will be required to implement some cache eviction policy, if not. Otherwise you may use excessive amount of memory for your registry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't use Generic Task in Dictionary. I mean I can't use: var samle =  new Dictionary<string, Task<T>>(). Anyway I get the idea, let me try.

Comment: @MRP Yeah, you should substitute concrete generic type parameter for sure. `Dictionary<string, Task<Response>>`. Where `Response` is some type representing response in your case. It may be `Task<string>` for example, if you expect to get response as string.